# Entity Framwork: error 0194: Multiple versions were encountered

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, metadata

I work from some years with Entity Framework on SQL Server, but this error is new for me.

I created a library project (DLL) with an EDMX model.

Then, I tested it from a little console application and it works.

Finally, I tried to use it in the real project that needs this DLL and... it obviously doens't work!!

The error I get is:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException: Schema specified is not
>   valid. Errors:  error 0194: All artifacts loaded into an
>   ItemCollection must have the same version. Multiple versions were
>   encountered.

The complete stackTrace is:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException: Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
>   error 0194: All artifacts loaded into an ItemCollection must have the same version. Multiple versions were encountered.
>      in System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EdmItemCollection.LoadItems(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 sourceFilePaths, SchemaDataModelOption dataModelOption, DbProviderManifest providerManifest, ItemCollection itemCollection, Boolean throwOnError)
>      in System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EdmItemCollection.Init(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 filePaths, Boolean throwOnError)
>      in System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.EdmItemCollection..ctor(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 filePaths, Boolean skipInitialization)
>      in System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.LoadEdmItemCollection(MetadataArtifactLoader loader)
>      in System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.<>c__DisplayClass5.b__0(String k)
>      in System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
>      in System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.GetMetadataWorkspace(DbConnectionOptions effectiveConnectionOptions)
>      in System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.GetMetadataWorkspace()
>      in System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext..ctor(EntityConnection connection, Boolean isConnectionConstructor, ObjectQueryExecutionPlanFactory objectQueryExecutionPlanFactory, Translator translator, ColumnMapFactory columnMapFactory)
>      in System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalConnection.CreateObjectContextFromConnectionModel()
>      in System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
>      in System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
>      in System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
>      in System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
>      in System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
>      in System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
>      in MailGunSender.MailManager.SendMail(String from, List`1 recipients, List`1 ccs, List`1 ccns, String subject, String text, String pathAttachment) in xxx:riga 261

Of course, I have installed Entity Framework in the caller project (with Nuget), as I did for the tester console project. But here it gives me this error. Do you know why?

My connection string is managed by this code:

```
public partial class Entities : DbContext
{
    public Entities(string nameOrConnectionString)
        : base(nameOrConnectionString)
    {

    }

    public void Close()
    {
        this.Dispose();
    }

    public static string GetConnectionString(string server, string db, string user, string pwd)
    {
        string cn = "Server=" + server;
        cn += ";Database=" + db;
        cn += ";uid=" + user;
        cn += ";Pwd=" + pwd;
        var providerSB = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(cn);
        var efConnection = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
        efConnection.Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient";
        efConnection.ProviderConnectionString = providerSB.ConnectionString;
        efConnection.Metadata = @"res://*";
        return efConnection.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your caller project? eg. ASP.NET MVC, WinForms? - Open NuGet manager to check the Entity Framework packages versions you installed on all projects are the same

Comment: Do you have multiple .edmx files? Have you tried refreshing or recreating any older files.

Comment: @Scrobi I have only one edmx file, inside the dll

Comment: @LukeTO'Brien the caller project is a windows service, while the test caller project is a console application

Comment: Are all projects & dll targeting the same version of .Net?

Comment: @Scrobi Yes, they are both .net 4.5

Comment: Have you tried defining the meta data file?. Metadata=res://* will load all mapping files in all references assemblies and you may have one that you don't mean to load.

Comment: @Scrobi I just tried to edit it as efConnection.Metadata = @"res://*/Database.Model.csdl|res://*/Database.Model.ssdl|res://*/Database.Model.msl;";

Comment: @Scrobi but with this mod, I get a new error: "The specified metadata path is not valid. A valid path must be either an existing directory, an existing file with extension '.csdl', '.ssdl', or '.msl', or a URI that identifies an embedded resource."

Comment: Is that the correct path? See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716756.aspx) for examples of the metadata.
I would think it should be something like res://Database.Model.Entities.csdl|res://Database.Model.Entities.ssdl|res://Database.Model.Entities.msl

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I just stumbled upon [this article](http://www.cloudyone.com/2015/03/entity-framework-error-0019-each-type.html), this guy had a similar issue and it was to do with **unique names for Entites**.
He also references two other articles.

Perhaps it will work in your case.

Comment: This answer ahs to be updated, the link is not an answer in stack overflw, and the reason is exactly what happens here. the link got broken

Comment: @catbadger Sorry about that, at one point it was working... Are you looking for an answer to a problem you are having?

Comment: @catbadger Perhaps you should create a new question?